# Multimaps with key = pair

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I've got a `multimap<pair<string,string>,vector> > mmap;`
and I would like to iterate over it with two loops:

1. on the first element of the key: `key.first`
2. then `key.second`

Does the `equal_range` method work in this case?
How to write it?

```
 pair<multimap<pair<string,string>,vector>::iterator,
 multimap<pair<string,string>,vector>::iterator> key_range = mmap.equal_range( ?? );
```

Comment: multimap<pair<string,string>,vector> > mmap;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multimap` only supports a single ordering, which for `pair` would be by default the lexicographical ordering over two elements:

```
(A, A) (A, B) ... (A, Z) (B, A) (B, B) ... (B, Z) ... (Z, A) ... (Z, Z)
```

If you need to index by two different keys you're best off using another container e.g. [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).  You could achieve the same effect yourself by e.g. storing items in a `list` and holding maps from a key to list iterators:

```
list<vector> items;
map<string, list<vector>::iterator> index1;
map<string, list<vector>::iterator> index2;
```